# Issue with grid position in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using a grid view , I need the grid view at center of the screen, How can I do that?

CSS:

```
 .grid-container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 302px;
    height: 452px;
    }

    .grid-row {
        width: 302px;
        height: 150px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }

    .grid-row_last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .grid-row a {
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 150px;
        margin-right: 1px;
    }
    .grid-row a:last-child {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="grid-container">
                    <div class="grid-row">
                        <a href="index.htm">
                            <img alt="alt..." src="http://th01.deviantart.net/fs12/150/i/2006/287/3/4/puppy_pug_3_by_WeiTat.jpg" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-row">
                        <a href="index.htm">
                            <img alt="alt..." src="http://th01.deviantart.net/fs12/150/i/2006/287/3/4/puppy_pug_3_by_WeiTat.jpg" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

From the above code I am getting the grid position as shown in below screen shot,
[image]

But I need the grid position as shown in below screen

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS should work for you (see demo http://jsfiddle.net/2map4/1/):

```
 .grid-container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

.grid-row img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Since you can't center vertically you will need to adjust `margin-top` to something that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

few changes is css: ***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G5482/)***

```
.grid-row {
        width: 302px;
        height: 150px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        text-align:center;
    }

.grid-row a {
       position:relative;
        /*float: left;*/
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 150px;
        margin-right: 1px;
  }
```